# Migrating to E4 - equivalent of PlatformUI.isWorkbenchRunning

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

In our Eclipse RCP 3.7 application we have quite a few calls to `PlatformUI.isWorkbenchRunning()`. 
For example most of the calls are guards around Workbench API calls, along the lines of
`

```
if (PlatformUI.isWorkbenchRunning()) {
    display = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();
} else {
    display = Display.getDefault();
}
```

We're migrating now to Eclipse RCP 4.4 and I can't find the correct way to replace these calls with RCP 4 compliant code.

I'm guessing I should inject some service / component and use that, but which component? IWorkbench cannot tell me whether it's running or not.

I would expect it to be quite a common problem, but could not find a solution by googling. Anyone solved this already?

Comment: e4 does not currently run headless so there isn't really an equivalent. If you expand a bit on what you are using the test for there may be something you can test.

Comment: @greg-449 I've updated the question with a code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e4 does not currently run headless so there isn't really an equivalent.

For access to the `Display` you can use

```java
Display.getDefault()
```

everywhere.

If you have a class derived from SWT `Control` available you can also use `Control.getDisplay()`

If you want to use the `asyncExec` or `syncExec` methods of `Display` you can use `UISynchronize` as an alternative:

```java
@Inject
UISynchronize uiSynch;

uiSynch.asyncExec(runnable);
```